# Receiving JSON data into my Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jsonp, http-post

I'm hoping this will be a quick answer (probably a 'No').

I have set up a web service on Server B to receive HTTP POST data in JSON format from Server A.  I don't have code level access to Server A, but I can manually trigger it to send data to my web service.

My current problem is that I have asked the Server A guys to send me a sample of what is being sent so I can program for the formats etc, but they are taking their sweet time responding.

I know the sending is working, and my WS is responding with my default return string (though Server A is seeing it as an error rather than success .. I don't know what they are expecting back for a successful transmission yet).

I am wondering if it is possible to receive and analyse the data without knowing exactly what is being sent? This way I can start my next phase of coding without needing to wait for them to provide a sample. Plus, I'm not sure how much the format will change for different jobs, so would be good to be able to accept whatever is sent and be able to look at it.

EDIT: To add more background.

Server A is a production application that we use. We have just found out that they have an API that can send data to us (HTTP POST in JSON format) each time one of our users completes whatever they are doing. We want to then store this data to build tables/stats for our clients to view (but that is another story).

Comment: As I understand that Server B is in your control, why cannot you decide on what format you accept and let the server A guys take care of your format! If the Server A is receiving an error may be they are doing something wrong!

Comment: Hi Nilesh, their system is already up an running - it is software that we use in production. I am just being impatient waiting for them to provide me with a sample of what their system sends to us. I can make it send to me now, but I don't know how to, or if I can, read it, without prior knowledge of what to expect, and have code in place to process it.

Comment: Isn't the data a sample of itself? You can get a sample of what their system sends you by getting actual data now, right? What would a sample do that the real thing wouldn't?

Comment: Daniel, the real thing would be great - I just don't know, with my level of knowledge, whether I can see that data when sent to my web service.
I can trigger Server A to send data to my web service, but without knowing what parameters etc, how can I read it? I haven't found any answers to this anywhere ... everything I have read tells me I need to know what parameters I am expecting and code for them.

Comment: I was about to ask that whether you could fire a request! If you are able to fire up a request then you can trace that on your server request variable. You can also use fiddler or some other tool on Server A to check what request is being sent over.

Comment: I can trigger Server A to send data (I have a web interface and just select a response to be sent and it makes 3 attempts), but I can't put any tools on it.
Can you tell me more (so I can search further) about your comment of "trace that on your server request variable"?

Comment: Nilesh, is this what you are referring to?
[ASP.NET Tracing Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Can't you read the real data in the same way you would read the sample data? How is one more readable than the other?

Answer (score 0):

You... can try putting together some dummy data, if you know enough about the type of data you'll be getting... But if you don't even know what shape it'll be, I don't know how in the world you would "analyze" it. Unless by "analyze," you mean get the size or something generic like that...

Comment: The app is a survey system. When a user completes a survey, Server A will send their responses to my web service. So I assume there will be a survey ID of some kind, each question and the choice selected, a case ID, time that they took to complete the survey, etc

Comment: If you feel it would be useful, you can try putting together those assumptions into some dummy data to play with. If you don't feel that would be useful, and don't have real or sample data to explore, I don't think there's much else to be done.